# When can I safely skip to the "end of day"

Tags: this-war-of-mine

In This War Of Mine, you can skip to the "end of the day" if you want.

However, sometimes there are random events (trader, people asking for help, people joining your shelter, people giving free stuff) that occur during the day. Do you miss these if you skip the day?

At what time of day can you safely skip to the night?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do miss these events when you skip the day.

i can not provide a Source for my observations but with around 15hrs into the game I feel confident to give you this advice:

The trader usually shows up quite early. The latest guy i had was around 2.pm but this seems to be only the first one on Day 2/3. Normally he is there within 2-3hrs into the day.

Same goes for other events. Very early into the day.

Trader and other events have never happend on the same Day for me.

So i'll always asume that after 2.pm i can safely skip the day.

Comment: These kind of events are random.

Comment: They don't seem to be completely random. Either they have a strong bias for occurring at morning or they don't occur at all after a certain time which seems to be around noon.